# Array data not getting loaded in store using extjs4.1

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I am using extjs 4.1 for loading data from an array. But data is not getting loaded. My code is following

```
var ghi=[];

var ghi=[{res :'25' , dir:'25',def: '56',dhr: '35',mon:'Jan'},......];
//alert("In Proces");



Ext.define('MyModelghi', {
               extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [{name: 'res',  type: 'float'},{name:'dir',type:'float'},              {name:'def',type:'float'},{name:'dhr',type:'float'},{name:'mon',type:'string'}]
        });
    storecahr2=Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: 'MyModelghi',
        data: ghi
    });
```

If i am un-comment the **alert** then data get loaded in store else if comment alert it return null value in store. can any one please tell me what i need to do to avoid this null value other than alert.

Comment: Just want to add that instead of using `alert` you can use `Ext.MessageBox.show`. Sample: [link](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1gu)

Comment: I want to remove alert. If i remove alert data is not loaded in store and store count to zero.

Comment: I don't understand how `alert` would interfere with data creation. Select Smile answered it correctly. I ran his code and removed the `alert`, it still worked. Sample: [link](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1h0)

Comment: actually my data is coming using ajax which  take time and store is executed first. So alert hold further execution ad data is loaded.

Comment: You should have included that information in the question. Anyway, if you use Ajax request, you can load your data to store in the success callback function. That way, your store will only get load when the Ajax request is completed.

Comment: Thanks worked in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find answer in this code.

```
var ghi = [{
    'res': '25',
    'dir': '25',
    'def': '56'
}];
alert('In Process');

var mymodel = Ext.define('MyModelghi', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [{name: 'res',  type: 'float'},{name:'dir',type:'float'}, {name:'def', type: 'float'}]
});

var storecahr2 = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: mymodel,
    data: ghi
});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Simpsons',
    store: storecahr2,
    columns: [{
        text: 'Res',
        dataIndex: 'res'
    }, {
        text: 'Dir',
        dataIndex: 'dir',
        flex: 1
    }, {
        text: 'Def',
        dataIndex: 'def'
    }],
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

For reference: http://jsfiddle.net/8Pqtx/6/

Comment: If i remove that alert('In Process'); it will not load. and i have graph.